# What is Guild ID in discord?

Tags: discord

So I'm trying to get my discord bot to work but a lot of tutorials/posts said to use this thing called `guild id` and i dont really like just blatantly copying code.

Thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the offical [Discord docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild) explain :

> Guilds in Discord represent an isolated collection of users and channels, and are often referred to as "servers" in the UI.

So guilds are basically servers and `guildId` is a unique server identifier.

Comment: I want to ask, why we need the guildId (serverId) in our bot ?
The bot is supposed to work on every server.

Comment: @YJRB you might wanna send/do different stuff for different server

Answer (score 1):

As per discord documentation: (https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498), guild ID is server ID. You might have created a server to add the bot in it, just go to the top left at your server's name and right click > copy server ID. It is not the name of the server but a numeric data type that you will get. You can then paste it in the config file or wherever required.